Example of finitely generated residually finite nilpotent-by-cyclic groups satisfy certain properties.
I am trying to find an example of a finitely generated residually finite group $G= N \rtimes_\phi \mathbb {Z} $, where  $N$ is a 2-step nilpotent group such that

$Q = \frac{G}{[N,N]} = \frac{N}{[N,N]} \rtimes_\phi \mathbb {Z} $ is finitely generated nilpotent.

$[N,N]$ is infinitely generated abelian.


(with an abuse of notation, here  $\phi$ also denotes the restricted automorphism on the characteristic subgroup and induced automorphism on the quotient.)
Here is the idea I have:
Let $K$ be an infinitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb {Q} ^n $ such that $K \rtimes_Q \mathbb {Z}$ is finitely generated for some $Q \in \mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb Q)  $, an automorphism on $K$.
Let $M \in \mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb Q) $ be a non-identity automorphism on $K$ and has all eigenvalue $1$.
For some choice of $K$, $M$ and $Q$, the group $G =( K \rtimes_M  \mathbb {Z}) \rtimes_\phi {Z}$, where $\phi (v, m) = (Qv, m)$, should satisfy the above two assumptions?
May I ask if my idea is correct? Are there other ways of constructing groups that satisfy the assumptions?

If N is 2-step nilpotent, then [N, N] is a quotient of $\Lambda^2 N_{ab}$, so should be finitely generated iff N is; but your G is finitely generated as well, f. g. nilpotent groups are polyciclic, therefore noetherian, and do not have any infinitely generated subgroups. Are you sure about your setup? If so, I can elaborate in the answer.

G might not be polycyclic, since N might not be finitely generated.

Every finitely generated nilpotent group is polycyclic; try to prove it yourself, it's not hard.

Thank you, but what about the lamplighter group, we can write it as the form $N \times \mathbb Z$, and N is abelian. But the lamplighter group is not polycyclic

Wreath products with infinite acting group are not nilpotent.

$\bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}2$  is nilpotent, but $\bigoplus{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_2 \rtimes  \mathbb{Z}$  is not nilpotent.

@xsnl, Sorry, I might have misunderstood you, do you mean $G$  in the question should be nilpotent?

Your condition 1 says that "G ... is f. g. nilpotent". If it really is what you want, there are no examples. I do not think that it is what you had in mind, because you insist that G is not necessarily nilpotent.

@xsnl thank you so much for pointing that out, I am really sorry about the typo. The group in condition 1 shouldn't be $G$.

@xsnl A quick question about your first comment, you mentioned that
``$[\mathrm{N}, \mathrm{N}]$ is a quotient of ${\Lambda}^2 {N}{a b}$". Does ${N}{a b}$ mean the abelianization of $N$, and ${\Lambda}^2$ mean the second term of the lower central series? Could you explain why $[\mathrm{N}, \mathrm{N}]$ is a quotient of ${\Lambda}^2 {N}_{a b}$?

Such examples of groups won't exist, as a nilpotent group with finitely generated abelianization is finitely generated.
